# Full house on table full house in hand

Tags: poker-texas-holdem

Ok scenario:

8 9 8 9 9 on table.

Player 1 has 8/4 in hand.
Player 2 has K/2 in hand.

Who wins?

I personally say split since table has higher full house. Am I right?

Comment: While it was technically answered by my answer on the question this was closed for, you did have to kind of read between the lines to get it. I have updated my answer on that question to clarify this edge condition.

Comment: It is a split pot, since each player only get to use 5 cards